# ENUM alternatives

Tags: php, mysql, enums

Is there a more efficient way of preventing users from editing a form text via firebug then posting the custom values?
I've heard quite a bit about not using ENUM's with large data sets. How else can i limit my users and prevent them from editing my forms to post altered data? An example would be a list of countries.

Thanks

Comment: Just test the user input, server-side, against the list of country. If it's not in the list, then send an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can never be sure of what is happening on the client side, firebug, greasemonkey they all give users power to do anything they wish. To be sure validate form on the server side too.

Comment: Yes, i agree but what is the most efficient method of doing this. I was thinking of using ENUM values but i heard this is not database efficient. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually u can use regular expressions in php for validating any input. If you haven't used them before, run to google, it's worth it!

Comment: So to ensure a form with countries has not been altered, i will have to compare the value against an array with all the countries in it?

Comment: There are many ways, using array is best. Or just keep a select option instead of input text

Comment: Yes but a select option can be altered with firebug